# Selecting all firsts with specific class with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I am using the code below to create a scrolling text. The problem is that I have multiple divs which contains `.vscontent` and I want to select the first of every `.vscontent` in the different "div-trees".
Right now only the first `.vscontent` of the first div is selected. How do I make this change happen to all of them at the same time?

Is there a `.vs-content:first` which selects all the firsts?

```
$(function() {
    var $this = $("#vs");
    var scrollTimer;
    $this.hover(function() {
        clearInterval(scrollTimer);
    }, function() {
        scrollTimer = setInterval(function() {
            scrollNews($this);
        }, 1500);
    }).trigger("mouseleave");

    function scrollNews(obj) {
        var $self = obj.find("#vs-container");
        var lineHeight = $self.find(".vs-content:first").height();
        $self.animate({
            "marginTop": -lineHeight + "px"
        }, 300, function() {
            $self.css({
                marginTop: 0
            }).find(".vs-content:first").appendTo($self);
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Try `find(".vs-content:first-child")` or `find(".vs-content:first-of-type")`, depending on your HTML structure this may already be enough

Comment: @elveti Doesn't work sadly!

Comment: Without seeing the HTML, we can't tell *why* @elveti 's comment doesn't work for you.  Giving the information you've provided, it should be adequate and *does work for the question* (just maybe not *how you're using it*)  Do you have multiple `id=vs-container`? or `id=vs`?  Also, `$self.find(multiple).height()` will need to be refactored to loop through each one.   If you break down the question to the *specific* parts that are not working, you'll get a better response.

Comment: @elveti was actually right. But I misunderstood my problem. What I really needed was to target the correct `#vs-container` and changing this from an ID to a class solved that problem. However there appeared a new problem which is linked to this, the jQuery now targets all the `.vs-content` which is what I want, but this means there is a duplicate created. Please check my Codepen here: https://codepen.io/jockebq/pen/PVzpWR

Answer (score 1):

salam, this work fine with me

```
 (".vs-content>:first-child")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should clarify how jq child selection work.

```js
$("div p:first-child").addClass("active")
```

```css
.active{

color:red;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

<p>1</p>
<p>1</p>
<p>1</p>
</div>

<div>

<p>1</p>
<p>1</p>
<p>1</p>
</div>


<div>

<p>1</p>
<p>1</p>
<p>1</p>
</div>


<div>

<p>1</p>
<p>1</p>
<p>1</p>
</div>
```